# Why is only one script value posting back to action from table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I will post more code as needed I just don't want to put up a huge block if I can avoid.
Basically in my MVC 3 application I have a list displaying in a table format.
The table contains a checkbox for each row to indicate row selection by the user. 
I'm trying to implement a file upload function on each row of this table.
This feature will only be available if the checkbox is checked.

The upload function uses valums Ajax uploader http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
This is the javascript function used, I have it in the view for now...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function handleCheckbox() {
        if ($(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            //$(this).find('#file-uploader-attachment').html($('#myHTML').html());
            createUploader();
            $(this).find('#file-uploader-attachment').removeClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");
            $(".qq-upload-button").css("margin-top", "-6px");
            $(".qq-upload-button").css("margin-bottom", "-20px");
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('#file-uploader-attachment').addClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");
            $(this).find('#file-uploader-attachment').html($('#myHTML2').html());
        }
    }

    $('tr').each(function () {
        handleCheckbox.apply(this); // We need to call the function initially using 'label' for this.
    });
    $('tr').on('click', handleCheckbox);

    function createUploader() {
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-attachment'),
            sizeLimit: 2147483647, // max size
            action: '/CalibrationViewer/AttachmentUpload',
            allowedExtensions: ['xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'csv', 'txt', 'rtf', 'zip', 'zipx', '7z'],
            params: {
                customer: CUST_NAME,
                calibrationId: CAL_ID
            },
            multiple: false,
            debug: false,
            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJson) {
                var resultMessage = document.getElementById('resultMessage');
                alert(responseJson.msg);
                $('#resultMessage').addClass('greenText');
                resultMessage.innerHTML = responseJson.msg;

                $('#attachment').prepend('<hr/><p><a class="attachment-file" href="' + responseJson.fileId + '">' + responseJson.fileName + '</a>' +
                    '<a class="attachment-delete" href="' + responseJson.fileId + '">X</a></p>');

                $('#no-attachments').remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The upload function actually works .... if there is only one row, if there is more than one row, the  ID of the last row is selected and used in the JsonResult.

I have the following script located in the foreach loop used in the view to populate the table, however I'm guessing the script tags can't to be used in this way.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
                 var CAL_ID = '@Model.ElementAt(index).Id';
                 var CUST_NAME = '@Model.ElementAt(index).CustomerName'; 
            </script>
```

I am only concerned about the Cal_ID parameter as CUST_NAME will be the same in all.
And this is the JsonResult in the controller.

```
  public JsonResult AttachmentUpload(string qqfile, string customer, int calibrationId, IPrincipal user)
```

The int calibrationId parameter in the json result is always the last row id in the table, whether its checked or not.

So really I have a few problems.
Correct row id is not selected if more than one row in table.
Upload btn only appears in the first row regardless which rows checkbox is checked.
And not sure how to allow for loop to ensure each row has a upload btn and that rows Id is used when uploading.

My apologies if this is too broad a question, I will add more code if required.

Comment: Just a tip: `$('tr').each(handleCheckbox);` will do, no need for that anonymous function that just does  `handleCheckbox.apply(this);`

Comment: Applied that change, thanks. Still learning when it comes to javascript/jquery.

Comment: NP. JS can throw people of, because of its C/Java-like syntax. But internally, the language was designed with a strong preference towards functional programming techniques. Your issue is probably caused by your repeated calls to `createUploader` in the `$.each` loop. The last time the `createUploader` function is called, is when it's processing the last tr. I think a closure might solve this (haven't looked at the code in detail, though)

Comment: can you expand , what you mean by "closure" in terms of code ?

Comment: A closure... like: `var module = (function(){ var closureVar = 123; return {getVal: function(){ return closureVar;}};}());`. Google IIFE, or the module pattern. It's a way to keep functionality and data encapsulated, bound together, with controlled (or no) exposure to the outside world

Comment: Not sure where and how to apply a closure in the above code block.